# DataRowCollection partial find

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering what happens when `DataRowCollection.Find` is given less keys than the primary key count? For example if the primary key is `LastName,FirstName,Initials` and you did `Find(['Smith','John'])` would it return the first matching row?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: I wonder too, did you try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it, and will return null. No exceptions, just null, no matter the number of actual matches. So now you know.